# Android kernel compile/deploy

Tags: android, android-source

Is it possible to download Android source code and compile it for any device?

What I'm trying to do is to play with the GSM code part and compile os and deploy it to my phone which is Motorola.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is, but it is difficult because your most phones don't share drivers. Motorola radio drivers are different than HTC. You are interested in porting. I'm not aware of any official guide offered unless you are a vendor working with Google.

There are however people who have tried to reverse engineer and document the process. The people at xda-developers are examples.

Specifically, if you are patient and have a lot of time, try starting somewhere like :

http://www.freeyourandroid.com/guide/porting-android

I found this post which shed some light when I asked myself what you are asking.

Comment: Thank you so much... Which phone is using open source radio drivers that I can buy to play with, or let's say which phone is the best for my development

Comment: :) that's the beauty of the nexus devices. They are meant to take a stock compile and the stock drivers.

Comment: Then I need to buy nexus, which Nexus by the way?

Comment: That depends on which version of android you want. Some older nexus devices will only run stock versions of android that were released about the same time the device was released. If you are interested in just emulating to test os changes you are making, look at marakana's android internals videos: http://marakana.com/techtv/index.html